# Скачивание изображений без формата в конце ссылки

Tags: python, requests

Собственно. Делаю возможность скачивания изображений драгндропом их с браузера. Однако я заметил, что далеко не все картинки, когда их открываешь "открыть изображений в новой вкладке" имеют в конце формат. Как можно скачивать их таким путём?

```
import sys, os, time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from threading import Thread
import requests
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.drop_label = QLabel(self)
        self.drop_label.resize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.drop_label.setStyleSheet('background-color: #302720;')
        self.drop_label.show()
        self.setWindowFlags( Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.show()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        file_formats = ('.png', '.jpg', '.gif')
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            mime = str(event.mimeData().text())
            if mime.startswith('http') is True and mime.endswith(file_formats) is True:
                Thread(target=self.downloader, args=(mime, 2)).start()
        else:
            # тут я сохраняю ссылку или текст просто как ссылку или текст
            pass


    def downloader(self, mime, x):
        print(x)
        current_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())
        img_name = os.getcwd() + r'\\Downloads\\images\\' + current_time + f'.{mime[-3:]}'
        img_link = requests.get(mime)
        load = open(img_name, "wb")
        load.write(img_link.content)
        load.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если формат файла может быть только из списка `file_formats`, то можно смотреть бинарную сигнатуру в начале файла и определять по ней.

```py
PNG_SIGNS = (b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n',)  # Сигнатуры png файлов
JPG_SIGNS = (b'\xff\xd8\xff',)  # Сигнатуры jpg файлов
GIF_SIGNS = (b'GIF87a', b'GIF89a')  # Сигнатуры gif файлов

file = ... # Файл изображения в бинарном виде

if file.startswith(PNG_SIGNS):
    print("This is PNG!")
elif file.startswith(JPG_SIGNS):
    print("This is JPG!")
elif file.startswith(GIF_SIGNS):
    print("This is GIF!")
else:
    print("Unrecognized file type")
```

---

Для ссылки, которую Вы привели в комментариях:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: url = "https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2071464/a8f69da8-cc1f-4a08-a19f-d2ae0b18aa09/s1200?webp=false"

In [3]: resp = requests.get(url)

In [4]: PNG_SIGNS = (b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n',)  # Сигнатуры png файлов
   ...: JPG_SIGNS = (b'\xff\xd8\xff',)  # Сигнатуры jpg файлов
   ...: GIF_SIGNS = (b'GIF87a', b'GIF89a')  # Сигнатуры gif файлов
   ...:
   ...: file = resp.content  # Файл изображения в бинарном виде
   ...:
   ...: if file.startswith(PNG_SIGNS):
   ...:     print("This is PNG!")
   ...: elif file.startswith(JPG_SIGNS):
   ...:     print("This is JPG!")
   ...: elif file.startswith(GIF_SIGNS):
   ...:     print("This is GIF!")
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("Unrecognized file type")
   ...:
This is JPG!
```

Comment: Файл в бинарном виде у Вас в `img_link.content`, как я понял.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как это применять. В img_link.content уже готовый файл, то есть уже нужный мне результат. В mime у меня приходит ссылка формата https:.png, и с такими ссылками проблем нет. Однако многие изображения идут ссылкой вроде: https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2071464/a8f69da8-cc1f-4a08-a19f-d2ae0b18aa09/s1200?webp=false, и вот как распознать такое?

Comment: Если Вы явно не знаете формат Вашего файла, то смотрите начало этого готового файла (`img_link.content`) на совпадение с бинарными сигнатурами. Примерно: `if img_link.content.startswith(PNG_SIGNS): print("png")`.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я недостаточно объяснил суть программы. Драгндропом я сохраняю любой контент. Если текст - он сохраняется как текст, если ссылка - как ссылка, а если ссылка на изображение - скачивается изображение. Но есть ссылки на изображения, которые не имеют в конце явного формата и сохраняются просто как ссылки. Хотя это изображение.

Comment: Приведите минимальный **воспроизводимый** пример. Я в коде вижу у Вас `img_link = requests.get(mime)`, т.е. Вы что-то скачиваете и потом вы записываете содержимое ответа в какой-то файл. Если в `mime` находится ссылка на файл без явного расширения, то я дал Вам ответ, как это расширение получить из самого файла,

Comment: Всё, разобрался, спасибо огромное!.